# Bash awk/sed extract multiple strings from a single large string using keywords

Tags: awk, sed, cut

Please help me figure out how to extract multiple substrings based on keywords.
I have been struggling with different methods using delimiters

My Input:

```
Inventory for 30844-ap01 NAME: AP1800 , DESCR: Cisco Aironet 1800 Series (IEEE 802.11ac) Access Point PID: AIR-AP1832I-E-K9, VID: V03, SN: KWC21420CKU
Inventory for ckh.hq-ap99 NAME: AP2700 , DESCR: Cisco Aironet 2700 Series (IEEE 802.11n) Access Point PID: AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9, VID: V03, SN: FCW2007N0ZQ
Inventory for AP0042.6843.ab78 NAME:  , DESCR:  PID: AIR-CAP1702I-E-K9, VID: V, SN: FCZ201622NY
```

Desired output:

```
30844-ap01 AIR-AP1832I-E-K9 KWC21420CKU
ckh.hq-ap99 AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9 FCW2007N0ZQ
AP0042.6843.ab78 AIR-CAP1702I-E-K9 FCZ201622NY
```

First string is anything between "Inventory for " and the next space

Second string is anything between "PID: " and the coma

Third string is an 11 char string after "SN: "

Comment: Please update the question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching "keyword value" pairs from semi-structured input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216148/matching-keyword-value-pairs-from-semi-structured-input)

Answer (score 3):

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's/Inventory for \([^ ]*\).*PID: \([^,]*\).*SN:/\1 \2/' file
30844-ap01 AIR-AP1832I-E-K9 KWC21420CKU
ckh.hq-ap99 AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9 FCW2007N0ZQ
AP0042.6843.ab78 AIR-CAP1702I-E-K9 FCZ201622NY
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best tool for such jobs is `grep` with `PCRE` features:

`grep -Po '(?<=Inventory for )[^ ]+|(?<=PID: )[^,]+|(?<=SN: ).{11}' data`

But this have the drawback of print each match in separate lines:

```
30844-ap01
AIR-AP1832I-E-K9
KWC21420CKU
ckh.hq-ap99
AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9
FCW2007N0ZQ
AP0042.6843.ab78
AIR-CAP1702I-E-K9
FCZ201622NY
```

So let's switch to `perl` and do the same:

```
perl -lne ' $i = $& if /(?<=Inventory for )[^ ]+/; $p = $& if /(?<=PID: )[^,]+/ ; $s = $& if /(?<=SN: ).{11}/; print join " ", $i, $p, $s' data
```

Print:

```
30844-ap01 AIR-AP1832I-E-K9 KWC21420CKU
ckh.hq-ap99 AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9 FCW2007N0ZQ
AP0042.6843.ab78 AIR-CAP1702I-E-K9 FCZ201622NY
```

Comment: Your `grep` approach has no drawbacks. Just pipe it to paste 3 lines at a time and delimited by space and voila you get the desired output.

Comment: Infact it is the`perl` approach that is needlessly wieldy. You could just as well have written: `perl -lne '$,=$";
  print
    /(?=.*(?:^|\h)Inventory\h+for\h+(\S+))
     (?=.*(?:^|\h)PID:\h+([^,]*),)
     (?=.*(?:^|\h)SN:\h+(\S{11}))
    /xg;
' file`

Comment: @guest_7 your `perl` is great. I will be glad to you if you post it as an answers, with explanation comment

Comment: @guest_7 it has the one drawback that it requires GNU grep for `-P` and so, like the perl solution, won't be available on all Unix systems.

Comment: @EdMorton The original question was tagged `bash` so, it seemed to me reasonable to use tool such as `grep` and `perl`

Comment: @YetAnotherUser that's absolutely fine, of course, I was just responding to guest_7 saying it has "no drawbacks" when in fact it has that one at least that perl isn't a mandatory POSIX tool, and the POSIX version of grep doesn't support `-P` and so those won't be available on all Unix boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`:

```
awk '{a=b=c=$0;
gsub(/^.*Inventory for | .*$/,"",a);
gsub(/^.*PID: |,.*$/, "",b);
sub(/^.*SN: /,"",c); c=substr(c,1,11);
print a,b,c}' input
```

First three variables `a`, `b` and `c` are set to current input record(`$0`). Then built-in function `gsub()` changes regex to empty string(`""`). The regex here `(/^.*Inventory for | .*$/` uses alternation has two patterns `/^.*Inventory for /` and `/ .*$/`. Alternation allows for alternate pattern in regex with
`|`. With `gsub()` from start of line(`^`) to `Inventory for` is changes to `""`. This means all characters from start of line to first string we want are removed. Similarly from space (after first string we want) to end of line are changed to `""`. Similarly `/^.*PID: |,.*$/` has two alternate patterns
`/^.*PID: /` and  `/,.*$/`. Both these are changed to `""`.

Next `sub()` changes `/^.*SN: /` to empty string and `substr(c,1,11)` takes 11 character long string from `c`.

Comment: very elegant, thanks for sharing the multiple variable attribution, I never saw that before